# Multiple alarms with AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarms

I'm currently at my wits' end.

In my application the user can set alarms by selecting the weekdays he wants and a time.

The below function checks the rule-set and looks for rules that have a time criteria. In those cases it will set an alarm for each day selected and will set it as repeating (every 7 days).

I have read quite some posts about the implication of multiple alarms (contrary to a single one). I would think I have taken the following into account:
- Using a fresh Intent for every alarm
- Using a fresh PendingIntent for every alarm
- Using a different request code for every alarm

The request codes are collected in an ArrayList so another function can clear all alarms when the program exits.

Now the problem: My alarms won't fire. I was able to track down the error to this function. The AlarmManager instance is fine. I'm setting up a test alarm at the very bottom (after the line with the asterisks). That fires. Why???

```
clearAlarms();
int i=0;    
ArrayList<Rule> allRulesWithTimeFrames = new ArrayList<Rule>();
allRulesWithTimeFrames = Rule.findRuleCandidatesByTimeFrame();
for(Rule oneRule : allRulesWithTimeFrames)
{
    for(Trigger oneTrigger : oneRule.getTriggerSet())
    {
        if(oneTrigger.getTriggerType() == Event_Enum.timeFrame)
        {
            Calendar calNow, calSet;
            Time setTime;

            if(oneTrigger.getTriggerParameter())
                 setTime = oneTrigger.getTimeFrame().getTriggerTimeStart();
            else
                 setTime = oneTrigger.getTimeFrame().getTriggerTimeStop();

            calNow = Calendar.getInstance();            
            calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();
            calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, setTime.getHours());
            calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, setTime.getMinutes());
            calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            // At this point calSet would be a scheduling candidate. It's just the day the might not be right, yet.

            long milliSecondsInAWeek = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;

            for(int dayOfWeek : oneTrigger.getTimeFrame().getDayList())
            {
                // --------------------
                // Here's a lot of code I will spare you. It only changes
                // the variable calSetWorkingCopy.
                // --------------------

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
                i++;
                String calSetWorkingCopyString = sdf.format(calSetWorkingCopy.getTime()) + " RequestCode: " + String.valueOf(i);
                Miscellaneous.logEvent("i", "AlarmManager", "Setting repeating alarm because of rule: " + oneRule.getName() + " beginning at " + calSetWorkingCopyString);

                Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(automationServiceRef, AlarmListener.class);
                PendingIntent alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(automationServiceRef, i, alarmIntent, 0);
                centralAlarmManagerInstance.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSetWorkingCopy.getTimeInMillis(), milliSecondsInAWeek, alarmPendingIntent);
                requestCodeList.add(i);
            }
         }
    }
}

        // ************* The below code is working *************
    // get a Calendar object with current time
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    // add 5 minutes to the calendar object
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("E dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
    String calSetWorkingCopyString2 = sdf2.format(cal.getTime());
    Miscellaneous.logEvent("i", "AlarmManager", "Setting repeating alarm because of hardcoded test: beginning at " + calSetWorkingCopyString2);
    Intent alarmIntent2 = new Intent(automationServiceRef, AlarmListener.class);
    PendingIntent alarmPendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(automationServiceRef, 0, alarmIntent2, 0);
    centralAlarmManagerInstance.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 5000, alarmPendingIntent2);
    requestCodeList.add(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this

```
PendingIntent alarmPendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(automationServiceRef, 0, alarmIntent2, 0);
```

with this

```
PendingIntent alarmPendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(automationServiceRef, 0, alarmIntent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was under kind of a time pressure and modified the program that way that I only set one alarm at a time and set the next one during onReceive(). That's has proven to be pretty reliable.